# Angular 2 and Firebase. How to do unique filter?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get some information on how to do a unique filter on `FirebaseListObservable`.

My data:

```
-key 
-- name: john smith
-- dept: hr
-key
--name: sam brown
-- dept: sales
-key
--name: nick reyes
-- dept: hr
```

how do I get angular2 to display hr and sales?

I was able to do this with angular 1 and firebase. But I am not sure how to do with angular 2. I can't seem to get any information from https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a work around since I cannot find anything on their github page in getting unique values. 
i went ahead and subscribed to it and saved it on another array by pushing it if it does not exist yet:

```
employees : FirebaseListObservable<Employee[]>;  this.employees = af.database.list('/employees'); this.departments=[];


    this.employees.subscribe(
    x =>{     
      x.forEach(element => {
      if(!this.departments.includes(element.department))
       { this.departments.push(element.department);}

    });        
  }   
  );
```

and now I can use it on my select as such:

```
<select name="depts" id="" #d (change)="filterBy(d.value)">    <option *ngFor="let d of departments" [value]="d">{{d}}</option></select>
```

Comment: is there another way of doing it?